# Check if .netfx3 is enabled, if not enable .netfx3

Tags: .net, powershell

Using PowerShell, I am not able to figure out how to check if .netfx3 is enabled, if not enable it with:

```
DISM /Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:NetFx3 /All
```

Also, can I run this using the system account? Please help!

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Windows 10 you can make use of the `WindowsCapability` cmdlets:

- [Get-WindowsCapability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dism/get-windowscapability)
- [Add-WindowsCapability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dism/add-windowscapability)
- [Remove-WindowsCapability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dism/remove-windowscapability)

You can check the State of the feature, and then Add it if it's not installed:

```
If ((Get-WindowsCapability -Online -Name NetFX3~~~~).State -ne 'Installed') {
    Add-WindowsCapability –Online -Name NetFx3~~~~
}
```

If the computer doesn't have internet access, you will need to specify the source location `–Source C:\source` when adding the feature.